# PyQt4 Spell Check with syntax highlighter

Tags: python, pyqt4, pyenchant

I have a problems with implement enchant spell check to QTextEdit().
I try:

```
from enchant.checker import SpellChecker
chkr = SpellChecker("en_US")
chkr.set_text(self.text.toPlainText())
```

And I can`t to use this with QTextEdit? How i can use this with self.text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you just need to do something like this:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from enchant.checker import SpellChecker
import re
import sys

class Main(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self,parent)
        self.initUI()

    def initToolbar(self):
        self.spellcheckAction = QtGui.QAction(QtGui.QIcon("icons/logo.png"),"Spellcheck",self)
        self.spellcheckAction.setStatusTip("Spell Check document")
        self.spellcheckAction.setShortcut("Ctrl+S")
        self.spellcheckAction.triggered.connect(self.spellcheckHandler)
        self.toolbar = self.addToolBar("Options")
        self.toolbar.addAction(self.spellcheckAction)

    def initUI(self):
        self.text = QtGui.QTextEdit(self)
        self.initToolbar()
        self.text.setTabStopWidth(33)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.text)
        self.setGeometry(100,100,1030,800)
        self.setWindowTitle("Writer")
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon("icons/icon.png"))

    def spellcheckHandler(self):
        chkr = SpellChecker("en_US")
        s = str(self.text.toPlainText())
        chkr.set_text(s)
        for err in chkr:
            self.replaceAll(err.word)

    def find(self, query):
        text = self.text.toPlainText()
        query = r'\b' + query + r'\b'
        flags = 0 
        pattern = re.compile(query,flags)
        start = self.lastMatch.start() + 1 if self.lastMatch else 0
        self.lastMatch = pattern.search(text,start)
        if self.lastMatch:
            start = self.lastMatch.start()
            end = self.lastMatch.end()
            self.moveCursor(start,end)
        else:
            self.text.moveCursor(QtGui.QTextCursor.End)

    def replace(self):
        cursor = self.text.textCursor()
        if self.lastMatch and cursor.hasSelection():
            self.text.setTextBackgroundColor(QtGui.QColor(0,255,0))
            self.text.setTextCursor(cursor)

    def replaceAll(self, query):
        self.lastMatch = None
        self.find(query)
        while self.lastMatch:
            self.replace()
            self.find(query)

    def moveCursor(self,start,end):
        cursor = self.text.textCursor()
        cursor.setPosition(start)
        cursor.movePosition(QtGui.QTextCursor.Right,QtGui.QTextCursor.KeepAnchor,end - start)
        self.text.setTextCursor(cursor)

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Main()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

To get suggestions use

```
chkr.suggest(err.word).
```